# GWT-RPC: cannot use javax.security.auth.Subject on server-side

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea, rpc, gwt-platform

I'm trying to implement an RPC-authorization service for my GWT/GWTP app, but I've got some problems. Intellij IDEA treats this using of Subject class on the server-side like an error:

`Class 'javax.security.auth.Subject' is not present in JRE Emulation Library so it cannot be used in client mode`

Here is the code snippet:

```
import javax.security.auth.Subject;

public class LoginServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements LoginService {
    public void loginUser(String login, String password) {
        Subject subject = UserContext.createSubject(connection, login, password, null);
    }
}
```

Why it mentions the 'client mode' when I'm trying to use this class on the server-side?
And it doesn't complain about that:

```
public class LoginServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements LoginService {
    public void loginUser(String login, String password) {
         UserContext.get().pushSubject(
            UserContext.createSubject(connection, login, password, null)
         );
    }
}
```

Why IDEA treats the former like an error but doesn't complain about the latter?

Comment: As far as I understand, GWT's JRE EL is a limited set of classes from the Java's JRE and hence the error you see that the class SUBJECT isn't available on the CLIENT side - are you checking on the CLIENT side by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
The problem was because of the redundant line in the *.gwt.xml file:

```
<source path="server"/>
```